# Using Regular Expressions on my Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, regex, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Is there an editor that I could install on the Raspbian OS to practice Regex with? If not, what about through Python? If so, is there a good python IDE out there for Raspbian that supports Regexs?

Comment: Check this http://jp.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=87306&p=614931

Answer (score 2):

Python itself supports regexes (via a built-in module). If you're just interested in playing around with them, `import re` in an interactive shell, and you have access to Python's regular expression engine.